# Spring IOC Bootstraping is it possible

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

My application is a standalone Java Application which uses Spring IoC. Bootstraping the application with ApplicationContext loads lets say 35 services in memory which are then used through out the JVM lifecycle instance of my application. This bootstraping requires about 6-7 minutes, which makes unit testing difficult.

This is the sequence of steps I have to do, which I am trying to avoid and still use Spring:

1. Bootstrap (Spring) and then actual business logic code.
2. Test code.
3. After testing I find something I want to change, which means I have to stop JVM, modify my code, start it up again, at this point Spring again takes about 6-7 minutes bootstraping the application.

How can test my modified code in the same JVM instance without being forced to restart the JVM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no easy solution to this

I know three possible ways to avoid your problem:

1. Try mocking parts of your services. Especially on junit tests this is recommended praxis. In IOC ready architecture it should be easy. On manual testing you can use fake services.
2. Switch to OSgI architecture. This will allow you to start, stop and redeploy single services. But you will have to use an OSgI container and it will take a multiple of 6-7 minutes to switch.
3. Try something like JRebel which promises to eliminate problems of hot deployment (after 14 days evaluation you will have to buy it). But many times extended hot deploment wont help because you will have to clean up your application context.

Comment: I guess this is something that is not exactly possible but the options you have suggested make sense and are useful.